# How to escape all file names in big directory copy with cp?

Tags: truenas, cp

I'm trying to copy an archive of user data in a folder from one disk over to another for our new `NAS` system using

```
cp -r dev-disk-by-label-MainAllData/ /root/backup/
```

but am getting many '`Invalid argument`' replies from cp for files that have characters like: ' ? - and possibly even just spaces.

Is there a way I can copy over a whole directory tree escaping the names of every file?

I'm on `FreeNAS 11.1`

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373284/cp-cannot-create-regular-file-invalid-argument) may answer your question.

TL;DR, certain file systems like NTFS and ZFS don't allow certain characters like `?` in file names.

[ZFS allowed characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23569/allowed-and-safe-characters-for-zfs-filesystem-in-freebsd)